# Why is this CORS Request failing?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, api, cors

I'm trying the following code for getting values from a web api, at the moment, hardcoded.
Yet it results in the 'error' part 100% of the time and I don't know why.
Any help is welcome.

```
    function SignIn() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:1200/Api/Values/3',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                'withCredentials': true
            },
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions) {
                debugger;
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(ajaxOptions);
            }
        });
    }
```

Server Side:

```
[EnableCors("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*", "*")]
public string Get(int id)
{
   return "{Name: 'Foo', Id: '1234',Rank: 7}";
}
```

Web.Config (server):

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console's Network tab to see what was sent and received header-wise?

Comment: Accept: */* ; Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate ; Accept-Language: nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3 ; User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0

Comment: JSONP is not CORS.  You should not be using JSONP.

Comment: Then could you give me an example on how to make and parse CORS requests?

Answer (score 0):

With `jsonp` you have to define a callback function. Be careful, JSON wants double quotes for keys and values:

```
[EnableCors("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*", "*")]
public string Get(int id)
{
   return "callback({\"Name\": \"Foo\", \"Id\": \"1234\",\"Rank\": 7})";
}
```

Now the Ajax:

```
function SignIn() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:1200/Api/Values/3',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        xhrFields: {
            'withCredentials': true
        },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions) {
            debugger;
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(ajaxOptions);
        }
    });
}
```

Or you can try your code just by changing `jsonp` to `json` for `dataType`.

Comment: Making the modifications you have requested (not the jsonp to json), I got the same error.
Renaming to json gave me a cors error again.

Comment: Strange, you cannot get CORS error using `jsonp` normally. What and where is the error ?

Comment: In the ajax he jumps into the 'error' part, with xhr.status = 200 and ajaxoptions = parsererror. Do you have a working version?

Comment: sadly, this didn't do the trick either. I just want to read the json or xml results, returned by another website, in this case my api ...

Comment: Sorry. Can you try by removing the semi-colon after the "callback({…})" ?

Comment: No good luck, changed it to : return "callback({\"Name\": \"Foo\", \"Id\": \"1234\",\"Rank\": 7})";